# How to make an anytime version of alpha beta pruning?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

I wish to use alpha beta pruning in a problem with following constraints:

- Terminal nodes are likely too distant to be found in most searches
- Instead I want to maximize an evaluation function
- There is a fixed time limit per search (say 1 second)
- Moves are made on a "WeGo" basis ie. we both move simultaneously (I still model this as a tree of my move then their move, but the game state is only updated every second level)

Hence I need an anytime version for alpha beta pruning which relies solely on an evaluation function.

I thought one way would be to iteratively deepen the alpha beta pruning search while keeping track of the frontier eg something like:

```
while (within time limit):

   frontier = alpha_beta_search(max_ply_depth, frontier)
   increment max_ply_depth

return (best node on frontier)
```

The frontier contains nodes in the last depth level which have not been pruned by alpha-beta. It's likely the time limit would be reached before an entire depth level is explored in which case the frontier would still contain some nodes from the earlier level.

Would this work or is there another way of implementing anytime alpha-beta pruning with an evaluation function?

Comment: An "anytime version of alpha beta pruning" can be made by repeatedly updating the currently-guessed-optimal moves after each depth finishes and then increasing the depth. ​ As long as the reachable part of state-space grows as (1+[Ω](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition)(1))$^{\text{depth}}$, that will be within a O(1)-factor of optimal. ​ (... continued) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: (continued ...) ​ ​ ​ I suppose the "anytime" part might still be tricky if you get to the point of state-space not growing that quickly, but otherwise the main thing is simultaneous moves - It can easily be the case there is a mixed strategy with a better guarantee than every pure strategy. ​ (Consider rock-paper-scissors.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​